# HTML/CSS - not getting the scroll

Tags: html, css

I am not getting the scroll on the browser. i have tried with overflow: scroll and also with no over flow.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}

.slide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:450px;
    width: 1041px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;

}

.meanu  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%;  
    right: 0;



}
```

Comment: Is it possible that it doesn't have anything to scroll? Seeing as nothing is going beyond the height of the window?

Comment: Could you provide an online example, like jsfiddle? Or at least, show us your html.

Comment: All the elements you mention are position:fixed, so are positioned relative to the browsers viewport - they won't cause a scroll. The page will only scroll if there are static elements which overflow the body.

Comment: Please provide your HTML. But based on your CSS, the issue may be with the `position` property on all of your elements. The `fixed` property takes elements out of the document flow. Try changing them to `relative` and see if you get your desired result.

Comment: thanks a ton guys , really the position was the problem . now its working :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because everything is `position:fixed` and these elements do not affect the flow.

As far as scrolling is concerned, the fixed positioned elements do not exist.